# Outlook addin index page loaded separately on a webpage before the whole addin is loaded inside outlook

Tags: visual-studio, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I use VS to write code. Initially I set the index page as a start page by mistake and since then the index page is loading separately then the whole project is being loaded inside the outlook web page. How do I rectify or undo this?
This is how the index page is loaded
 [index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm1MI.png)

Then the outlook is loaded separately with the add-in
[outlook add-in page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6Nsv.png)

Comment: Can you help us with some more details ?
What is the documentation that you followed ?